# Paragraph text entered in the subsubsection

Tags: sectioning, acm

I am writing a document of class

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
```

When I create a subsubsection

```
\subsubsection{Data1}
%
For HIV....

\subsubsection{Data2}
```

Instead of getting

```
1.3.1 Data1
  For HIV
```

I am getting

```
1.3.1 Data1 For HIV
```

I tried adding new lines by \, \nointendent and some comments between but it didn't work. How to fix it ?

Comment: latex supports inline and run-in heading, it seems that the class you are using uses run-in. It is usually not advisable to change the layout of a publisher supplied journal class, as the whole point of such a class is to enforce the journal style and remove choice from the author.

Comment: So you think that the article layout is enforcing the text to appear in the same line as a title? that's strange and would make the thing less readable...

Comment: The default classes such as `article` also switch to run-in style for lower level section headings, but one level lower, `\paragraph` and `\subparagrah`

Comment: ah ok so instead of using sections and subsections i should use paragraphs ?\

Comment: As I say this seems quite normal (the standard latex classes also do this) and it is the publishers choice. It is likely to be simple to change (just change the sign of the argument in `\@startsection`) but check with your publisher if they would accept such a change in the layout.

Comment: it is always easier to find duplicates once you know the answer:-) Yes that would change the style (but for some journals doing that would bar the document from being published, so check first....) Journals can only have a "house style" if authors are stopped from choosing their own style in each paper.